# How to completely delete an RDF node/instance from a graph database?

Tags: sparql, rdf, graphdb

Good day, I am using Graphdb to store some triples as seen in the image below. This particular RDF node uses a regular URI http://example/regular/uri. What I wish to do is to not only completely delete all properties attached to this node, but also delete the node itself. (with the result that http://example/regular/uri does not appear in the graph database any longer)

[image: RDF node example in graphdb]

So far I am only able to delete all properties, but I am not able to delete the actual RDF node itself. It seemed rather simple, but the more I research online, the more this seems impossible unless clearing the complete graph.

I have tried simple "delete where" queries as shown in [example 11](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#deleteInsert) of SPARQL documentation. And i have also tried using simple "delete where"-queries using the wildcard operator as shown in the query below:

[image]

Is there a way to delete such RDF nodes? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "delete node"? And RDF dataset consist of RDF triples, thus, you can only delete RDF triples. Nodes are parts of triples but never exist alone

Comment: @AKSW Thanks for the comment. yes, I had trouble giving it a name as well, but graphdbh calls them that . the RDF 'node' is simply the object identified with the URI.

 In this example I am able to delete the properties of the triples (for example deleting the "dc:language"-relationship and its value "english") But if I delete every single property of this object, (in this case <http://example/regular/URI>) the 'object' still exists, only without properties.

So this object, while it doesn't serve any use anymore, still appears in my graph database. 
Did I manage  to explain it somehow?

Comment: Did you verify that no triples exist after the delete? just doing `select * { {<uri> ?p ?o} union {?s ?p <uri>}}` or `describe <uri>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A node exists in a graph as long as there is one or more triples with that node in subject or object position. So the easiest way would be to issue two delete statements, one deleting all statements with the node in subject position and one deleting all statements with the node in object position. But if you need/want to do it with a single operation you can do that as well with filters.

Comment: Yes, it has mostly to do with me not really understanding rdf yet. It dissappeared once all relationships with the node were gone.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample that delete **uri://node/to/delete** from **uri://my/graph** :

```
DELETE { GRAPH <uri://my/graph> {   
   ?s ?p ?o .
}}
USING <uri://my/graph>
WHERE {
  { 
    ?s ?p ?o .   VALUES ?s { <uri://node/to/delete>}
  } UNION {
    ?s ?p ?o .   VALUES ?o { <uri://node/to/delete>}
  }
}
```